# Using map function with external dictionary (global)

Tags: python, python-3.x, map-function

I'm trying to improve the computing time of my code so I want to replace for loops with map functions.

For each key in the dictionary I check if it is bigger than a specific value and inserting it to a new dictionary under the same key:

My original code is:

```
dict1={'a':-1,'b':0,'c':1,'d':2,'e':3}
dict_filt = {}
for key in dict1.keys():
   if dict1[key]>1:
        dict_filt[key] = dict1[key]*10

print (dict_filt)
```

output is: {'d': 20, 'e': 30}
and this works 
but when I try with map:

```
dict1={'a':-1,'b':0,'c':1,'d':2,'e':3}
dict_filt = {}
def for_filter (key):
    if dict1[key]>1:
        dict_filt[key] = dict1[key]*10

map (for_filter ,dict1.keys())

print (dict_filt)
```

I get an empty dictionary

I tried to make it work with lambda:

```
map (lambda x: for_filter(x) ,dict1.keys())
```

or define the dictionarys as global but it still doesnt work.

I'll be glad to get some help

I don't need the original dictionary so if it's simpler to work on one dictionary it's still ok

Comment: "I  am trying to improve the computing time of my code so i want to replace for loops with map functions. " That will not do that at all. This will often be *slower* since function call overhead is high. Also, you shouldn't use `map` for side effects. The *reason* this isn't working is because `mao` returns a lazy iterator. Your function is never called, and the map object is immediately discarded

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary-comprehension instead of  `map`:

```
{k: v * 10 for k, v in dict1.items() if v > 1}
```

**Code**:

```
dict1 = {'a':-1,'b':0,'c':1,'d':2,'e':3}

print({k: v * 10 for k, v in dict1.items() if v > 1})
# {'d': 20, 'e': 30}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` is lazy: if you do not consume the values, the function `for_filter` is not applied. Since you are using a side effect to populate `dict_filt`, nothing will happen unless you force the evaluation of the `map`:

Replace:

```
map(for_filter, dict1.keys())
```

By:

```
list(map(for_filter, dict1)) # you don't need keys here
```

And you will get the expected result.

But note that this is a misuse of `map`. You should use a dict comprehension (see @Austin's answer).

## **EDIT:** More on `map` and lazyness.

### TLDR;

Look at [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> map(function, iterable, ...)
>
> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

### Explanation

Consider the following function:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     print("x =", x)
...     return x
...
```

This function returns its parameter *and* performs a side effect (print the value). Let's try to apply this function to a simple range with the `map` function:

```
>>> m = map(f, range(5))
```

Nothing is printed! Let's look at the value of `m`:

```
>>> m
<map object at 0x7f91d35cccc0>
```

We were expecting `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` but we got a strange `<map object at 0x7f91d35cccc0>`. That's lazyness: `map` does not really apply the function but creates an **iterator**. This iterator returns, on each `next` call, a value:

```
>>> next(m)
x = 0
0
```

That value is the result of the application of the function `f` to the next element of the mapped iterable (`range`).  Here, `0` is the returned value and `x = 0` the result of the `print` side effect. **What is important here is that this value does not exist before you pull it out of the iterator.** Hence the side effect is not performed before you pull the vlaue out of the iterator.

If we continue to call next, we'll exhaust the iterator:

```
...
>>> next(m)
x = 4
4
>>> next(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Another way to get all the values of the iterator is to create a `list`. **That's not a cast**, but rather the constrution of a new object and the consumption of the old one:

```
>>> m = map(f, range(5))
>>> list(m)
x = 0
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

We see that the side effect `print` is performed for every element of the range, and *then* the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` is returned.

In your case, the function doesn't print anything, but makes an assignement to an external variable `dict_filt`. The function is not applied unless you consume the `map` iterator.

I repeat: **do not use `map` (or any list/dict comprehension) to perform a side effect** (`map` comes from the functional world where side effect do not exist).

Comment: It worked! thank you very much. but can you elaborate please why it dosen`t work without the casting?

Comment: @ZeevSlobodnik Please use Austin's answer, because this is the good way to achieve what you want. See my edit for more on map and lazyness.